# How to spy componentWillMount using jest and enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test whether componentWillMount was called and for that my test is

```
test('calls `componentWillMount` before rendering', () => {
  let fn = jest.fn(SomeComponent.prototype.componentWillMount)
  mount(<SomeComponent />)
  expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

But even though the componentWillMount method is called, the test does not pass.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know if the other answers have helped with your question, but you shouldn't need to test componentWillMount. React should already do that testing for you.

More relevant to your testing would be to test the functions or actions you are putting in that method for your component.

If you are making some API call, running a function based on props, or anything else, that is what you should be testing for. Mock the function/action/code that `componentWillMount` triggers, and make assertions and expectations on that.

Example:

Component:

```
class YourComponent extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    /*this fetch function is actually what you want to test*/
    this.props.fetch('data')
  }

  render() {
    /* whatever your component renders*/ 
  }    
}
```

Tests:

```
test('should call fetch when mounted', () => {
  let mockFetch = jest.fn()

  const wrapper = mount(<SomeComponent fetch={mockFetch}/>);

  expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
  expect(mockFetch).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(mockFetch.mock.calls[0]).toEqual(['data'])
});
```

Comment: could you elaborate if the function called inside componentWillMount is actually part of the class itself, like: `this.fetch('data');` ?

Comment: `this.prop.fetch('data')` is just an example. For this, I am just calling a function that is passed to `YourComponent` through props. So no, not part of the class itself. You can really test for anything, but the underlying point here is you don't really need to test `componentWillMount` or any of the react lifecycle methods. React/Facebook does that for you. Just test that the code you have written inside those lifecycle methods works.

Comment: yes, I get that. Sorry I wasn't clear enough. I understand how to test everything inside the lifecycle function if they are functions that were passed via props. But what about functions that belong to the component? How would you test that that function was called and such? If `this.props.fetch()` was instead `this.fetch()`, how would you test that inside `componentWillMount`, the function `this.fetch()` was called a number of times?

Comment: The easy way would be to go the BDD for that, make assertions around the changes that method should make. If it is supposed to be changing some portion of the UI, you can use enzyme's `mount` function, expecting a certain DOM element/Component to exist/not exist. Otherwise, I would use shallow wrap the Component and use `wrapper.instance().yourMethod(your_arguments)` to test that method is acting properly. I do hope someone else can chime in here on this because this is the best way I can think of doing it.

Comment: Does this mean that everything you do within any of these lifecycle methods needs to be a function call? For example, if i have a car class and on `componentDidMount` I want to start the car and shift the gear, both actions should be function calls (`startCar` and `shiftGear`), rather than writing the logic in the `componentDidMount`? Is that a fair understanding? I see that when you are using Redux this can be achieved through use of `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` and `connect` middleware.

Comment: @Mr.Doomsbuster You can also use the `.instance()` wrapper method from enzyme to call react lifecycle methods. Something like `wrapper.instance().componentDidMount()` will allow you to write tests without extracting the logic into other functions. I feel that it is cleaner and easier to work with code if the logic is extracted out, but that is the fun of it. It's up to you :)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
test('calls `componentWillMount` before rendering', () => {
  const onWillMount = jest.fn();
  SomeComponent.prototype.componentWillMount = onWillMount;
  mount(<SomeComponent />);

  expect(onWillMount).toBeCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I would first `spy` on the component's `componentWillMount` method but also use `.and.CallThrough()` to prevent it from mocking its contents. Hope this helps:

```
it('should check that the componentWillMount method is getting called', () => {
    spyOn(SomeComponent.prototype, 'componentWillMount').and.callThrough();

    const wrapper = mount(<SomeComponent />);

    expect(wrapper).toBeDefined();
    expect(SomeComponent.prototype.componentWillMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the above answer addresses the issue. Which is jest allow you to spyOn a method but does not allow you to `callThrough` while spying on its call status. The solution that worked best for me is to setup the test with a component that has `componentWillMount` defined. Leaning on jest will just make things more complicated.

```js
describe('componentWillMount', () => {
  const calls = []
  class Component1 extends Components {
    componentWillMount() {
      calls.push(new Date)
    }
    render() { ... }
  }
  
  afterEach(() => calls.splice(0, calls.length))
  it('has been called', () => {
    mount(<Component1 />)
    expect(calls.length).toBe(1)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `wrapper.instance().componentWillMount();` to call `componentWillMount()` method from test script..