# Jest / Enzyme can't mock class property

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm currently writing tests for React components with Jest an Enzyme. I'm stuck when I have to mock a class property function, written with arrow syntax : the mock is not applied.

Here is an excerpt of the tested component :

```
class MaClass extends React.Component {
  ...
  componentWillMount () {
    this.getNotifications()
  }
  getNotifications = () => {
    axios.get(window.Routing.generate(
      'api_notifications_get_collection'
    ), {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(response => {
      this.setState({
        notifications: response.data
      })
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('Error : ', error)
    })
  }
  ...
}
```

And here is the test :

```
import React from 'react'
import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-15'

import NotificationsComponent from './NotificationsComponent'

configure({adapter: new Adapter()})

describe('Testing NotificationsComponent', () => {
  /**
   * This should call getNotifications
   */
  test('getNotifications should be called', () => {
    let wrapper = shallow(<NotificationsComponent />)
    const getMock = jest.fn()
    wrapper.instance().getNotifications = getMock
    wrapper.update()
    expect(getMock).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

As far as read, this is the right way to do for regular methods. But it seems that class property functions written with arrow syntax can't be mocked this way.

My terminal throws an error concerning what's inside the tested component method :

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'generate' of undefined`

Which means that the mock is not passed through.

Would anyone point out where is my mistake please ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong lifecycle hook for this. `componentWillMount` is called "inside" `shallow(<NotificationsComponent />)`. Thus the original `getNotifications` has been invoked.

`wrapper.update()` forces a re-render and does not re-mount the component, so your assignment of the mock does not achieve the desired effect.

Comment: I used `mount` with no luck either.

Comment: `mount` will reset your component... you could pass in `getNotifications` as prop, like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598559/how-to-spy-componentwillmount-using-jest-and-enzyme . If you are using redux or other state management, this would be beneficial in any case.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure that this feats my needs as in its example, he defines `this.props.fetch('data')`. I'm not testing props, I'm testing class properties, like in the example I gave earlier : `getNotifications = () => {...}`. The important part here is that it uses `= () =>`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is there is no good way to mock a class property that is an arrow function. The best workaround I have found so far is move the class property to a class method and bind that method in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getNotifications = this.getNotifications.bind(this);
}

getNotifications() {...}
```

Then in your test you will be able to properly use `jest.spyOn()`:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(MaClass.prototype, 'getNotifications');
```

Here is some additional info on it:
https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2018/06/13/spyon-react-class-method/

Hope that helps!

Comment: You're right. I moved from custructor binding because of flow type issues I could'nt reslove at the time.