# How can I use Jest to test componentWillMount in react-native?

Tags: react-native, jestjs

My code is as follows:

```
export default class {
    componentWillMount=()=>{...}
    render()=>(...return...)
}
```

In the componentWillMount function, I get some data from web api. Now I want to create unit test about it. What should I do ? orz...

Comment: I think sample code might help you . @Alen.KW

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to test `componentWillMount`, react will do that. You should rather test the web api request that you put inside componentWillMount.

You can check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598559/how-to-spy-componentwillmount-using-jest-and-enzyme/43099813) for more details that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log(" ********** componentWillMount ******* ");
    this.apiLogic
  }
  apiLogic = () => {
    console.log("Fetch you Api ");
  }
```